# If a function is continuous at point $a$, does there always exist point $b$ such that the function is Riemann integrable $[a,b]$?

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

As the question states, if a function is continuous at a point $a$, does there always exist point $b>a$ such that the function is Riemann integrable in the interval $[a,b]$?

For continuity we use the epsilon delta definition.

Comment: Yes, just find a way to use the result that a continuous function is Riemann integrable on a closed interval.

Comment: @Clayton do you disagree with Zestylemonzi's answer? OP doesn't assume continuous on the interval

Comment: The answer is yes if you didn't assume $b > a$ haha

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Nope, this is not true. Consider the function
$$ f(x) =
  \begin{cases}
    x       & \quad \text{if } x \in \mathbb{Q}\\
    -x  & \quad \text{if } x \in \mathbb{R}\backslash\mathbb{Q} \\
  \end{cases}
$$

This is certainly continuous at $0$ but does not satisfy your integrability condition.